# Can't Click Start Button on Web App with Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flexbox, automated-tests, cypress

Learning Cypress, couldn't find answer on Google. Here is the html of the button and surrounding elements. I believe this page is a vue.js web app with flex css.

```
<div class="row no-gutters align-center justify-center" data-v-11111111="">
    <div class="v-card__actions" data-v-11111111="">
        <button class="title v-btn--contained theme--dark v-size--x-large green"     data-v-11111111="" type="button">
            <span class="v-btn__content">
                Start
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my Cypress describes:

```
describe('Begin the form', () => {
    it('I can start the form', () => {
      cy.visit('https://this.app.com/#/start');
      cy.get("span[class='.v-btn__content']").click();
    });
  });
```

When I run the above in Cypress I get the following in my Cypress results:

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: span[class='.v-btn__content'], but never found it.
```

Answer (score 1):

ok then try this

```
cy.get('.v-btn--contained').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
cy.get('.v-btn__content').click();
```

if it does not work check that element is visible

```
cy.get('.v-btn__content').should('be.visible');
```

Comment: Nope, nothing. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
cy.contains('Start').click();
```

This should work out for this question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).